# how to convert a SQL source to pseudo-code

Tags: mysql, sql, pseudocode

What is the right way to write pseudo-code for SQL source code?

for example, I have this SQL source:

```
DELETE temp FROM temp LEFT JOIN DBSNFP
ON temp.CHROM=DBSNFP.CHROM AND temp.POS=DBSNFP.POS 
WHERE DBSNFP.CHROM IS NULL
```

and its equivalent pseudo-code that I wrote:

```
IF not exist in (Join INPUT and DBSNFP on INPUT.chrom==DBSNFP.chrom AND INPUT.pos==DBSNFP.pos) THENE
    Delete
END IF
```

Is what I wrote right? If not, how should I write it?

Comment: Just asking: Why do you want to write pseudocode when you already have real code?

Comment: This seems like a school project where you have to hand out both pseudocode and code. Teachers keep claiming to do pseudocode before, but students always do code first as it is easier to debug then convert it to pseudocode to get 100%

Comment: @OllieJones its for university project. we need to write pseudo code for the theoretic part.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the specification -- the pseudocode -- for this query should read as follows:

> Delete every row from `temp` lacking any matching rows in `DBSNFP`,
>   where "matching" is defined as sharing common values in the `CHROM`
>   and `pos` colummns.

But, if I may be so bold, it's better design discipline to state such things in the language of your application's domain. The purpose of this sort of pseudocode is to help out the person who needs to debug your application ten years from now. I don't know your domain, so I will guess.  Something like this:

> Before using the `temp` table to assign chroma values to positions in
>   the product to be delivered, remove all the items in `temp` that don't
>   match the official master list of chroma values and positions. (in the
>   `DBSNFP` table).